# Capture and manipulate data from another application

Tags: python, c

I have a game written in C (for Windows). I'm struggling to find a way to write a Python application that reads data and control this game.
For example: When my character hitpoints reach 50% or less, my Python program that is capturing the data constantly sends a command to use a item restoring the hitpoints.
The Python scripting I can do very well, but I don't know what use to capture the data from this game.

PS.: I don't want a mouse/keyboard/graphic automation. I know there is a program exactly how I described. Written in Python, to control this game that is in C. The game window does no even need to be in focus for the Python program control it.

There's any Python module that can access another application, read and send commands?

**EDIT:**

I now can read the memory (gotten via CheatEngine).
With a while loop I'm printing every second the correct amount of hitpoints (in hex):

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *
import time

OpenProcess = windll.kernel32.OpenProcess
ReadProcessMemory = windll.kernel32.ReadProcessMemory
CloseHandle = windll.kernel32.CloseHandle

PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = 0x1F0FFF

pid = 3488   # I assume you have this from somewhere.
address = 0x0019F438  # Likewise; for illustration I'll get the .exe header.

buffer = c_char_p("The data goes here")
bufferSize = len(buffer.value)
bytesRead = c_ulong(0)

processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, pid)
while True:
    if ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, address, buffer, bufferSize, byref(bytesRead)):
        print "Success:", buffer
    else:
        print "Failed."
    time.sleep(1)

CloseHandle(processHandle)
```

But soon it begin to print weird values:

```
Success: c_char_p('\x8e') -> 142 |------------------
Success: c_char_p('\x8e') -> 142 |
Success: c_char_p('\x8e') -> 142 |
Success: c_char_p('\x90') -> 144 |
Success: c_char_p('\x90') -> 144 |
Success: c_char_p('\x90') -> 144 |
Success: c_char_p('\x90') -> 144 | This entire block is correct
Success: c_char_p('\x92') -> 146 | The hitpoints are increasing
Success: c_char_p('\x92') -> 146 |
Success: c_char_p('\x92') -> 146 |
Success: c_char_p('\x92') -> 146 |
Success: c_char_p('\x94') -> 148 |
Success: c_char_p('\x94') -> 148 |
Success: c_char_p('\x94') -> 148 |___________________
Success: c_char_p('\x0e') -> 14      |
Success: c_char_p('\x0e') -> 14      | Here it becomes 
Success: c_char_p('\x0e') -> 14      | print weird stuff
Success: c_char_p('\x06\xfa\x82p0')  |
Success: c_char_p('\x06\xfa\x82p0')  |___________________
```

Comment: Can't you send data _command_ over udp/tcp to C game ?

Comment: @P0W I don't know. It's like sending the data directly to the game server?

Comment: Yeah, kind of. You basically need to be able to talk to python through an interface not necessarily a sever-client design.

Comment: But what can I use to make python "see" the game informations, like the actual hitpoints, the monsters in screen, etc?

Comment: The game would need to expose an interface via a socket that allows you to read and write that data.  Otherwise, you're talking about hacking the game's memory which is highly OS (to read/write another process's memory) and implemention (how the game's code is written) specific.

Comment: Once, with CheatEngine I could get the memory address for HitPoints, but I don't know how to treat this, how to make Python read this memory address. This is what I need.